# UICollectionViewCell contentView padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, padding

I want to set padding for `contentView` from inside of custom `UICollectionViewCell` so that it is smaller than the cell itself.
I tried doing that by setting anchors for `contentView` but this view seems to always be equal size of the cell.

This is what I tried.

```
 self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
 [self.contentView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:5].active = true;
 [self.contentView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leftAnchor constant:5].active = true;
 [self.contentView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor constant:-5].active = true;
 [self.contentView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bottomAnchor constant:-5].active = true;
```

For a quick solution I created another view inside `contentView` that I can anchor the way shown above but I hope for a cleaner solution.

Comment: add a view inside  `contentView` and add constraint to that view instead of `contentView`

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try setting `edge` insets for the `contentView`, but if you take that approach you should be pinning the `subviews` to the layout margins guides and not anchors directly.

I come from Swift, but I think you'll understand me:

```
contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
someSubview.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```